# Reprojecting coordinates using GDAL library

Tags: c++, gdal, coordinate-systems, mingw-w64

I'm trying to reproject a `lat/lon` coordinate in the `WGS84` system to an `UTM` one in the `SIRGAS 2000` coord system.

Using `GDAL`, I started with changing a known utm coordinate to the lat/lon counterpart **in the same** coordinate system (29 N), just to check that I wrote the right code (I'm omitting error-checking here):

```
OGRSpatialReference monUtm;
monUtm.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
monUtm.SetUTM(29, true);

OGRSpatialReference monGeo;
monGeo.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");

OGRCoordinateTransformation* coordTrans = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&monUtm, &monGeo);

double x = 621921.3413490148;
double y = 4794536.070196861;

int reprojected = coordTrans->Transform(1, &x, &y);
// If OK, print the coords.

delete coordTrans;
coordTrans = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&monGeo, &monUtm);
reprojected = coordTrans->Transform(1, &x, &y);

// If OK, Print the coords.
delete coordTrans;
```

The coordinates `621921.3413490148, 4794536.070196861` [correspond to the Moncelos region in northern Galicia](https://www.google.es/maps/place/43%C2%B017%2737.6%22N+7%C2%B029%2749.3%22W/@43.2937796,-7.497016,375m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en). The forth-and-back transformation seems to work right: the lat/lon coordiantes are the correct ones and when projecting back to UTM, I get **the same** as the originals:

```
UTM:          621921.34135 , 4794536.0702
Lat/lon:      43.293779579 , -7.4970160261
Back to UTM:  621921.34135 , 4794536.0702
```

Now, reprojecting from `WGS84 lat/long` to `SIRGAS 2000 UTM`:

```
// Rodovia dos Tamoios, Brazil:
//  - UTM          -> 23 S
//  - WGS 84       -> EPSG:32723
//  - SIRGAS 2000  -> EPSG:31983

OGRSpatialReference wgs;
wgs.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");

OGRSpatialReference sirgas;
sirgas.importFromEPSG(31983);

coordTrans = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&wgs, &sirgas);

double x = -23.57014667;
double y = -45.49159617;

reprojected = coordTrans->Transform(1, &x, &y);
// If OK, print results
delete coordTrans;

coordTrans = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&sirgas, &wgs);
reprojected = coordTrans->Transform(1, &x, &y);
// If OK, print results.
```

this doesn't give the same results:

```
WGS84 Lat/Lon input:      -23.57014667  ,  -45.49159617
SIRGAS 2000 UTM output:   2173024.0216  ,  4734004.2131
Back to WGS84 Lat/Lon:    -23.570633824 ,  -45.491627598
```

As you can see, the original `WGS84 lat/lon` and the `back-to_WGS84 lat/lon` coords aren't exactly the same, unlike the first test case. Also, the `UTM x-coord` has 7 digits (I thought it was limited to 6 (?) ).

[In Google Maps](https://www.google.es/maps/dir/-23.57014667+-45.49159617/-23.570633824+-45.491627598/@-23.5704275,-45.4921635,136m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m9!4m8!1m3!2m2!1d-45.4915962!2d-23.5701467!1m3!2m2!1d-45.4916276!2d-23.5706338?hl=en), we can see that there's a difference of 27 meters between the two points (original point is represented by a *circle*. My "back-reprojected" point is represented by a *dagger*).

Finally, the question: am I doing the reprojection right? If so, why is there a 27 meter difference between reprojections in the second test case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to swap your axis order to use Cartesian X/Y space or Lon/Lat, and not "Lat/Lon" order.

Setting this should work.

```
double x = -45.49159617;  // Lon
double y = -23.57014667;  // Lat
```

The difference you saw from your round-trip conversion was from projecting outside the bounds for the UTM zone due to a swapped axis order.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Since the reprojection was 'successful' I didn't realize that order of the coordinates was wrong.